Why does the QGraphicsView viewport not clip the scene in this simple example?
This simple app creates a window of size 800x600, then places a viewport of size 100x100 at 0,0
If I draw two rectangles in the scene at 100,100 (of size 100, 100) and 300, 300 (of size 200x200), I would expect them both to be clipped by the view port
Instead I see the whole window with both rectangles rendered.
Is the view being auto-fitted that I am not aware of?
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('QGraphicsView Clipping Example')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Create a central widget and set a layout
        central_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Create a QGraphicsScene
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 600)

        # Create a QGraphicsView with a smaller viewport
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.view.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)  # Smaller viewport
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

    def add_object(self, item):
        self.scene.addItem(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()

    # Add a rectangle item to the scene
    new_item = QGraphicsRectItem(300, 300, 200, 200)
    mainWin.add_object(new_item)
    new_item = QGraphicsRectItem(100, 100, 100, 100)
    mainWin.add_object(new_item)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


Calling setGeometry() on a widget that is being managed by a layout is completely pointless. Use setMaximumSize() or setFixedSize(), or just don't add the widget to the layout and just ensure that it's properly "parented" (add central_widget to the constructor, in this case)
